# Why is an imported value being mutated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not understanding why, in a file where I define a React class, a variable assigned to an import and one that *is never mutated* still changes.

```
import statuses from '../statuses'; // array of 6 items

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.statuses = statuses;
  }

  render() {
    const statusOptions = this.statuses;
    if (statuses.length === statusOptions.length) statusOptions.push(obj);
    console.log(statuses.length); // 7 (?!?!)
  }
}
```

I have no idea why `statuses` would be updated at all, and why it would get mutated as if it were `statusOptions` here. (To be clear, I also logged `statuses` itself, and sure enough, `obj` had been pushed to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`statuses`, `this.statuses` and `statusOptions` are *all **references** to the same object*.

Push to one, and it'll appear in all three.

Comment: See something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) to better understand how javascript deals with variables.

Answer (score 1):

All three variable are the same, share same reference. You can use:

```
this.statuses =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(statuses))
```

```js
var a=[1,2,3]
var b=a;
c=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
a.push(4);

console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

This is like `this.statuses=statuses` , but changing one variable does not affect another one.

Comment: Not going to work that well with an array.

Comment: You are right, that was for an object. But this trick (I edit answer) will work for eather.

Comment: Thank you. I believe they share the same `referent` (not the same `reference`).